# REPLACE in SQL does not function predictably

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to replace every instance of a particular character in a string by another, 's' & '#' in this case
So, San Jose becomes #an Jo#e
I am using the following queries:

```
UPDATE city SET NewName = REPLACE(Name,'s','#') WHERE(ID<5000);
UPDATE city SET NewName = REPLACE(Name,'S','#') WHERE(ID<5000);
SELECT * FROM city WHERE Name LIKE "%s%" OR "%S%";
```

This is what the table looks like:

```
ID   Name           CountryCode District Population NewName
4   Mazar-e-Sharif  AFG Balkh   127800  Mazar-e-#harif

5   Amsterdam   NLD Noord-Holland   731200  Amsterdam

15  Enschede    NLD Overijssel  149544  Enschede

19  Zaanstad    NLD Noord-Holland   135621  Zaanstad

20  Â´s-Hertogenbosch   NLD Noord-Brabant   129170  Â´s-Hertogenbosch

21  Amersfoort  NLD Utrecht 126270  Amersfoort

22  Maastricht  NLD Limburg 122087  Maastricht

33  Willemstad  ANT CuraÃ§ao    2345    Willemstad
```

I am using [this database](http://downloads.mysql.com/docs/world.sql.gz). I have also added a new column to the table, NewName

Comment: not working means ? what is the output ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this in one step:

```
UPDATE city
    SET NewName = REPLACE(REPLACE(Name, 's', '#'), 'S', '#') 
    WHERE(ID < 5000);
```

Actually, the first will do if the collation for the column is case-insensitive.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use next approach:

```
UPDATE city SET NewName = REGEXP_REPLACE(Name, '/[s]/ig', '#') WHERE(ID<5000);
```

OR update your request

```
UPDATE city SET NewName = REPLACE(REPLACE(Name,'s','#'),'S','#') WHERE(ID<5000);
```

Comment: How do you explain the city names where not even a single instance of s has been replaced?Examples:

21  Amersfoort  NLD Utrecht 126270  Amersfoort

Comment: @AayushMahajan, first request change the field, second - rewrite it. You have to join them into one or use regexp